# Respond with a status unauthorised (401) with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the following Rails 4.2 controller:

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:error] = 'Access denied'
        redirect_to root_url
      end
      format.json do
        render json: {}, status: :unauthorised
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When, with RSpec 3, I try to call this `index` action and expect to have the status 401 I always have the status 200.

The only moment where I got the 401 is to replace the `index` action content with `head 401` but I would like to respond with the error 401 and also build a "nice" body like `{ error: 401, message: 'Unauthorised' }`.

Why is the `status: :unauthorised` ignored ?

Comment: I just built a quick test app and your spec passes. It likely to be another `before_filter` or `before_action` as @shoji suggests.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem with Rails 4.2.0 and Rspec-rails 3.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to replace my controller with this following:

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:error] = 'Access denied'
        redirect_to root_url
      end
      format.json do
        self.status = :unauthorized
        self.response_body = { error: 'Access denied' }.to_json
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using `render` is not preventing the called action to be executed. Using `head :unauthorized` is returning the right status code but with a blank body.

With `self.status` and `self.response_body` it's working perfectly.

You can see have a look to the source code my gem where I had this issue here: https://github.com/YourCursus/fortress

Answer (score 22):

Use error code instead of it's name:
`render json: {}, status: 401`

Comment: The two are equivalent in Rails, take a look at the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option).

Comment: English isn't my native language so I use codes to avoid mistakes

Comment: @AlexTonkonozhenko I have already tried this and it's not working.

Comment: this also works for: `redirect_to(root_path, status: 401)`

Answer (score 4):

Replace `unauthorised` by `unauthorized`

Comment: Sorry... auto correction from OSX. It's not working with `unauthorized`.

Comment: I don't really understand why it's not working... With RSpec I'm doing a `get :index, format: :json` and then `expect(response.status).to eql(401)` but I all the time have a 200 code.

Comment: Which spec file do you use, request, controller, etc?
And, don't you have `before_filter` or `before_action` in `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Ha! Adding some debugs shows me that the controller action is called anyway. With an HTML I don't have issues as I'm using `redirect_to`, so the controller action is prevented, while with JSON I set the `status: 401` but after in the controller action it's switching back to `200` I guess.

Comment: I found a solution which looks not nice to me... looking at the source code of the `head` method, I saw their using `self.status = ` and `self.response_body = `. I replaced my `render` and `head` with this and it's working. I have the correct body and status code.

Comment: Well it seems to be the way Metal works: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L42.